# RAM to read/write in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to use RAM in order to read/write. My address is an integer value and it should be a memory of integers. This is my code below but i keep getting an error.

This is from my data path where the address selection is from a register of integers.

Code:

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Mem is
generic(    width:  integer:=4;
        depth:  integer:=4;
        addr:   integer:=2);
port(   Clock:      in std_logic;   
    Enable:     in std_logic;
    Read:       in std_logic;
    Write:      in std_logic;
    Read_Addr:  in integer;
    Write_Addr:     in integer; 
    Data_in:    in integer;
    Data_out:   out integer
);
end Mem;

--------------------------------------------------------------

architecture behav of Mem is

type ram_type is array (0 to 31) of 
    integer;
signal tmp_ram: ram_type;

begin   

    -- Read Functional Section
    process(Clock, Read)
    begin
    if (Clock'event and Clock='1') then
        if Enable='1' then
        if Read='1' then
            -- buildin function conv_integer change the type
            -- from std_logic_vector to integer
            Data_out <= tmp_ram(conv_integer(Read_Addr)); 
        else
            Data_out <= (Data_out'range => 'Z');
        end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

    -- Write Functional Section
    process(Clock, Write)
    begin
    if (Clock'event and Clock='1') then
        if Enable='1' then
        if Write='1' then
            tmp_ram(conv_integer(Write_Addr)) <= Data_in;
        end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

end behav;
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Error:

```
Error (10514): VHDL aggregate error at Mem.vhd(41): can't determine type of aggregate -- found 0 possible types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your faulty code is:

```
if Read='1' then
    -- buildin function conv_integer change the type
    -- from std_logic_vector to integer
    Data_out <= tmp_ram(conv_integer(Read_Addr)); 
else
    Data_out <= (Data_out'range => 'Z'); -- Faulty line
end if;
```

`Data_out` is an integer, not a `std_logic_vector` or derived type. Thus, it doesn't have a range (only arrays do, `std_logic_vector` beeing defined as an array of `std_logic`). Furthermore, it can't take the value of `'Z'` since it is not an `std_logic`; `integers` can only be assigned integer values.

If you need `Data_out` to become high-impedance when `enable` is `'1'` and `read` is `'0'` as you described, you will need your memory output to use `std_logic_vector` or `signed/unsigned`.

Also, I should advise you against using `integers` without range if your target is synthesis. By VHDL standard, `integers` are 32 bits. Synthesis tool **may** optimized the netlist and use less bits, but you shouldn't count on it. Either constrain the range of your `integers` (`signal x: integer range -4 to 3`) or use `signed/unsigned`.

Comment: what if i wanna use doubles instead of integers? meaning 64 bits.

Comment: Double imply floating point, so I assume you mean quadwords, 64 bits integers? They don't exist as integer in VHDL, you have to use `signed/unsigned` or `std_logic_vector`. For example, `signal x: signed(63 downto 0)`.

Comment: So signal x: signed(63 downto 0) would mean an integer of 64 bits? as in double? Isn't that considered binary not int?

Comment: It a signed integer of 64 bits. All integers in VHDL, including literals, are restrained to 32 bits. `signed` must thus be used in binary/hexadecimal if you need literals larger than 32 bits. Otherwise, you can add/substract/multiply `signed`. It's the only way to represent integer value of more than 32 bits signed.

Comment: thank you for your help, would you be able to assist me in my other problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386031/sin-cos-functions-in-vhdl?noredirect=1#comment48861253_30386031